# How pass JSON array as parameter to another YAML template in AzureDevOps pipeline

Tags: azure-pipelines-yaml

I have a situation where I need to pass JSON array as parameter into another YAML template, I have already sanitized the json array but still getting below error.

Array

```
{\"arr\":[{\"priority\":1,\"ipAddress\":\"<IP Address>\",\"description\":\"\",\"name\":\"test\",\"action\":\"Allow\"},{\"priority\":1,\"ipAddress\":\"<IP Address>\",\"description\":\"\",\"name\":\"test1\",\"action\":\"Allow\"}]}
```

Error

```
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1689449876215_inlinescript.ps1:30 char:338
+ … dt-sem-use2" ipSecurityRestrictions=" [{\"action\":\"Allow\",\"descri …
+                                                               ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1689449876215_inlinescript.ps1:30 char:433
+ … :\"64.136.252.163/32\",\"priority\":1},{\"action\":\"Allow\",\"ipAddr …
+                                                               ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1689449876215_inlinescript.ps1:30 char:528
+ … \",\"priority\":1,\"tag\":\"Default\"},{\"action\":\"Allow\",\"ipAddr …
+                                                               ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1689449876215_inlinescript.ps1:30 char:641
+ … priority\":1000,\"tag\":\"ServiceTag\"},{\"action\":\"Deny\",\"ipAddr …
+                                                               ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1689449876215_inlinescript.ps1:38 char:366
+ … dt-sem-use2" ipSecurityRestrictions=" [{\"action\":\"Allow\",\"descri …
+                                                               ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1689449876215_inlinescript.ps1:38 char:461
+ … :\"64.136.252.163/32\",\"priority\":1},{\"action\":\"Allow\",\"ipAddr …
+                                                               ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1689449876215_inlinescript.ps1:38 char:556
+ … \",\"priority\":1,\"tag\":\"Default\"},{\"action\":\"Allow\",\"ipAddr …
+                                                               ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
At D:\a\_temp\azureclitaskscript1689449876215_inlinescript.ps1:38 char:669
+ … priority\":1000,\"tag\":\"ServiceTag\"},{\"action\":\"Deny\",\"ipAddr …
+                                                               ~
Missing argument in parameter list.
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingArgument
```

Can anybody help what I am doing wrong here.
Many thanks in advance.

Below is yaml code that I am trying

```
- task: AzureCLI@2
            name: 'AllowedIPs'
            displayName: 'GET allowed IPs'
            inputs:
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.ams_service_connection }}
              location: $(region)
              scriptType: pscore
              scriptLocation: inlineScript
              inlineScript: | 
                $jsonResult = az deployment group create -g "<groupname>" --template-file '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/infrastructure/api/ip-restrictions.json' --parameters apiManagementName=<amsname> apiManagementRg=<amsrgname> | ConvertFrom-Json
                $ips = @($jsonResult.properties.outputs.ips.value) | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
                $val = $ips.replace('"', '\"')
                Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ips;isoutput=true]"$val



- template: deploy/arm-deploy.yml
            parameters:
              displayName: 'Configure ADT API IP restrictions'
              azureSubscription: ${{ parameters.adt_service_connection }}
              location: $(region)
              resourceGroupName: '<groupname>'
              force: true
              file: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/infrastructure/api/adt-api-confog.json'
              parameters: 
                name="<serviceprincipalname>"
                appServicePlanName="<serviceplanname>"    
                apiRgName="<groupname>"   
                ipSecurityRestrictions="$(AllowedIPs.ips)"
```

Comment: Can you add a pipeline code where you pass this parameter?

Comment: Try t remove quotes around `$(AllowedIPs.ips)`, also the quotes here `isoutput=true]"$val` look suspicious as well.

Comment: @IhorKorotenko Thanks for the suggestion, Issue is solved. Sorry for late reply. I noticed that I need to replace double quotes with \"" and keep isoutput=true]$val inside double quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the fix I was able to resolve the issue.

```
 $deployment = az deployment group create --resource-group "<resource-group-name>" --template-file '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/infrastructure/api/adt-ip-restrictions.json' --parameters apiManagementName=<app service website name> apiManagementRg=<website-resource-group-name> --query 'properties.outputs.ips.value'
$result = @($deployment) -replace '"','\""' // I had to make a change in this line
```

earlier I was doing

```
$result = @($deployment) -replace '"','\"'
```

Then changed it to

```
$result = @($deployment) -replace '"','\""'
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=ips]$result"
```

Then in next task

```
az deployment group create --resource-group "<website-resource-group-name>" --template-file '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/infrastructure/api/update-sites.json' --parameters name="<appservice-website-name>" location="<location>" ipSecurityRestrictions="$(ips)"
```